# HTML - image width and height versus responsive image

Tags: html, responsive-images, cimg

On my webpage I am using some responsive images (using bootstrap 5 img-fluid class). In CSS I have just defined width: 100% for it and as it is responsive, I can't add `width` and `height` to the img tag itself.

However then the W3C validator and also SEO tools,PageInsights etc. yields that my images doesn't have width and height defined.

Of course if I try to add the image fixed size to img tag, it stays fixed and not responsive anymore.

Any suggestions to validate and also stay responsive, possibly without removing bootstrap img-fluid class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I finally solved it by inserting width and height to the img tag and in CSS I kept the `width: 100%; height: auto;` and now it validates and it is also responsive.

Comment: this is correct way, but make sure to add the css in the html element like `style="width: 100%; height: auto;"` but not in the .css files as the HTML's style overrides the stylesheets

Comment: did you add random values to html attributes? Or you've add equal values into tag and in the css file?